# Decimals in denominators

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the system:$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{0.01-x}{0.02}-0.5 \le
>  \dfrac{2-3x}{0.01}\\ \dfrac{3-x}{0.1} \le
>  \dfrac{6x+8}{0.4}-5\end{cases}$$

I am a little confused about what to do when we have decimals in a denominator. Is it a good idea to multiply by $10$?

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: Indeed you may multiply numerator/denominator by $10$ or $100$. You can also repel the denominators. But you can also take the decimal numbers for what they are: numbers.

Comment: turn them into fractions

Comment: "*is it a good idea to multiply by 10*"  That depends on what your final goals are and how many intermediate steps you wish to take.  It is certainly reasonable to do, but you could go about it faster with a bit more attention.  $\dfrac{0.01-x}{0.02}=\dfrac{0.01-x}{0.02}\times 1 = \dfrac{0.01-x}{0.02}\times\dfrac{50}{50}=\dfrac{0.5-50x}{1}=0.5-50x$.  With practice, you can become comfortable going straight from $\dfrac{0.01-x}{0.02}$ straight to $0.5-50x$ without explicitly writing out the inbetween steps.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you for the response! I really appreciate it! If we want to treat the second fraction the same way: $\dfrac{2-3x}{0.01}=\dfrac{2-3x}{0.01}\times 1=\dfrac{2-3x}{0.01}\times \dfrac{100}{100}=\dfrac{200-300x}{1}=200-300x$, right?

Comment: Yes, and division by $1$ can be ignored.  Part of my goal though with writing what I had was to point out that you can multiply just single fractions at a time by $1$ (*which can take a form like $\frac{50}{50}$*) rather than both sides of the equation by some value, and further that what you multiply by need not be explicitly a power of ten.  Certainly, you can accomplish the same end goal a number of different ways.  What matters most is your comfort in performing the steps, but after that speed can also be a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply the first equation's denominator by $50$, you get:

$$
(0.01-x)-0.001\leq4-6x
$$

Remember that each zero in a decimal is a power of ten and the rest you can see as numbers from $1-9$. Like what I did with the first fraction on the $LHS$, I multiplied the denominator by $10$ first which gave me $\frac{0.01-x}{0.2}$ and all I did was then multiply by $5$ which gave me  $0.01-x$.

Remember that you have to multiply the rest of the equation by that amount too - that's why the $RHS$ multiplied by $2$ since $0.01*50=0.5$ which means $\frac{1}{0.5}=2$ so I have to multiply the numerator by $2$.

See if you can do the second equation using this method - remember to look for an amount which will eliminate all the fractions. I'm thinking $10$ for the second equation, but I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: You might want to think that through again.  To clear fractions, you'd multiply through by 1/100, not 100.

Comment: @B.Goddard Thanks for spotting that, I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I would multiply the first fraction by $100$ on top and bottom to get

$$\frac{1-100x}{2}.$$

The second fraction is $\frac{1}{2}$ and if you
multiply the third fraction by $100$ top and bottom you get  $200-300x$.  So the first inequality becomes

$$\frac{1-100x}{2} +\frac{1}{2} \leq 200 - 300x.$$

Multiply through by $2$ to finish clearly fractions to get

$$1 - 100 x +1 \leq 400 -600x$$

$$500x \leq 398$$

$$x\leq 0.796.$$

Treat the second inequality the same way, multiplying each fraction, top and bottom by $10$.

Comment: Thank you! It's $-\dfrac12$.